# How to send soap request using http post without creating xml file?

Tags: soap, http-post

I don't need to create xml file just want to send a soap request as:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();

SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

SOAPMessage req = createSoapSubsribeRequest("SUBSCRIBE");
```

I need this request to get sent via httppost.